# Missing required parameters in Route

Tags: laravel, routes, controller

**Hi, I have problem with routes, it's always return "Missing Required Parameters".Please see my code below. Thank you! I think my route is wrong, what should I do?**

//Controller Code

```
public function index($id = 0,$dateStart = null, $dateEnd = null)
    {
        //$current_date = date('Y-m-d');
        // $attendances= Attendance::select('Name','CheckIn','CheckOut','Note','Date','TotalHours')- 
>where('Date','=',$current_date)->get();
        // return view('attendance.index',compact('attendances'))
        if($id == 0 && $dateStart == null && $dateEnd == null)
        {
            $current_date = date('Y-m-d');
            $attendances = 
Attendance::select('Name','CheckIn','CheckOut','Note','Date','TotalHours')- 
>where('Date','=',$current_date)->get();
           
            return view('manage.index',compact('attendances'));
        }
        elseif ($id != 0) 
        {
            $sUser = User::select('name')->where('id','=',$id)->get();
            $attendances = 
Attendance::select('Name','CheckIn','CheckOut','Note','Date','TotalHours')->where('user_id','=',$id)- 
>get();
            return view('manage.index',compact('attendances','sUser'));
        }
        elseif($dateStart != null && $dateEnd == null)
        {
            $attendances = 
Attendance::select('Name','CheckIn','CheckOut','Note','Date','TotalHours')
>whereBetween('Date',$dateStart,$dateEnd)->get();
            return view('manage.index',compact('attendances'));
        }
       // return view('manage.index');

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    }
```

**And here is my route**.

```
Route::get('manageattendance/{id}/{dateStart}/{dateEnd}', 
[App\Http\Controllers\ManageAttendanceController::class, 'index'])->name('manageattendance');
```

Comment: That code doesn't seem to have anything to do with that route

Comment: I wouldn't know how, that code seems to be irrelevant. [Edit] your question, post the _complete_ error message and the corresponding file/code

Comment: The error is related to how you are calling the route. None of the code you have provided is related. Please provide the full error as it will tell you the file and line.

Answer (score 0):

if you set the parameters in function must say for route these parameters are not required are optionally  add **?** after each parameter

```
Route::get('manageattendance/{id?}/{dateStart?}/{dateEnd?}',
```